# JAXB Unmarshal returning null for nested object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm having some trouble trying to use unmarshal from JAXB. I'm receiving the following XML from a webservice:

```
<retEnviCte xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="3.00"><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><cUF>43</cUF><verAplic>RS20170524123312</verAplic><cStat>103</cStat><xMotivo>Lote recebido com sucesso</xMotivo><infRec><nRec>431000011194855</nRec><dhRecbto>2017-06-13T13:27:22-03:00</dhRecbto><tMed>1</tMed></infRec></retEnviCte>
```

And I want to unmarshal it into TRetEnviCTe class that looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TRetEnviCTe", propOrder = {
    "tpAmb",
    "cuf",
    "verAplic",
    "cStat",
    "xMotivo",
    "infRec"
})
public class TRetEnviCTe {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String tpAmb;
    @XmlElement(name = "cUF", required = true)
    protected String cuf;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String verAplic;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String cStat;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String xMotivo;
    protected TRetEnviCTe.InfRec infRec;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "versao", required = true)
    protected String versao;

//Getters and setters

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "nRec",
        "dhRecbto",
        "tMed"
    })
    public static class InfRec {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String nRec;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String dhRecbto;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected BigInteger tMed;

        /**
     * Gets the value of the nRec property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getNRec() {
        return nRec;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the nRec property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setNRec(String value) {
        this.nRec = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the dhRecbto property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getDhRecbto() {
        return dhRecbto;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the dhRecbto property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setDhRecbto(String value) {
        this.dhRecbto = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the tMed property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigInteger }
     *     
     */
    public BigInteger getTMed() {
        return tMed;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the tMed property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigInteger }
     *     
     */
    public void setTMed(BigInteger value) {
        this.tMed = value;
    }

  }
}
```

When I do the unmarshal through the method bellow the fields are filled correctly, except the InfRec object that is created but has null values in his attributes.

```
private static TRetEnviCTe getDocumentRet(String xml) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context2 = JAXBContext.newInstance(TRetEnviCTe.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller2 = context2.createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller2.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), TRetEnviCTe.class).getValue();
}
```

[image: Null values]

Object Factory:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

private final static QName _Signature_QNAME = new QName("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Signature");
private final static QName _RetEnviCte_QNAME = new QName("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte", "retEnviCte");

    /**
     * Create an instance of
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TRetEnviCTe }{@code >}}
     *
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte", name = "retEnviCte")
    public JAXBElement<TRetEnviCTe> createRetEnviCte(TRetEnviCTe value) {
        return new JAXBElement<TRetEnviCTe>(_RetEnviCte_QNAME, TRetEnviCTe.class, null, value);
    }
}
```

Any idea about what may be causing this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The `infRec` field in TRetEnviCTe is not annotated with `@XmlElement`

Comment: But I have other classes without this annotation that is working properly. Looks like the @XmlElement is default and only required when you want to pass parameters like the required=true.

Comment: As long as infRec object created problem must be with its setters. double check them. I was able to get correct result right out of your example with setters I put there. Also, how did you unmarshal your example without @XmlRootElement defined as @XmlRootElement(name = "retEnviCte") ? is it a part of larger document in real? and how your ObjectFactory class looks like? or jaxb.index?

Comment: Hi Vadim, I wrote my getters and setters in the question as well as the ObjectFactory. It's not a part of a larger document, the <retEnviCte> is the root element.

Comment: Can you try adding the namespace to the '@XmlElement annotation in your inner classes ?

Comment: Hello Dimpre, your suggestion solved my problem! I wrote the @XmlElement with namespace in the TRetEnviCTe.InfRec and it's working fine now. The final annotation is "@XmlElement(required = true, namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte")". Thanks a lot man!